# Give a form field focus while out of viewport?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to be able to give a formfield (via javascript or otherwise) focus while it's out of the viewport, without having the scrollbar move to shift it into the viewport.

Is that possible?

I know & understand that it'll pop into the viewport as soon as the user starts typing - that works fine for my use case.

Answer (score -1):

Simply done by creating a JavaScript function onLoad in the body tag and sending the focus to the form field doesn't matter if it's out of viewport.

HTML

```
  <body onload="FocusMe();">
  <input type="text" id="FocusTo">
```

JAVAscript

```
  function FocusMe () {
  document.getElementById("FocusTo").focus();
  }
```

Comment: That will cause the page to scroll.  I don't want it to scroll.